# Unable to see in DevTools POST CORS request data

Tags: ajax, cors, google-chrome-devtools

[image: request exists]

[image: dont see actual request, just preflight]

how can I see actual POST request in Chrome Devtools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with "Disable cache" enabled. I tested with Skype login and I see the allowed `POST` request after the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request responded with success.

[image: CORS]

You may also find [chrome://net-internals/#events](http://chrome://net-internals/#events) useful for more detailed networks logs.

Comment: `Disable cache` is always checked in my devtools.
I see the second request in `net-internals`, but it's ugly looking and the most important I don't see sent and received payload, so it's mostly useless for debug goals.

Comment: @beornborn What happens when you toggle back and forth between `XHR` and `All`? I just saw another thread that mentioned that refreshed it for them.

Comment: yes, I found it in all. For some reason devtools thinks that it's an xhr request. buggy. Thanks, man

Comment: @beornborn Glad you found it. It would be useful to get a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) submitted if possible, though ideally it needs to be able to be easily replicated.